# How to sort dd/mm/yyyy format with group by dates?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(15), TransDate, 103)  AS TransDate, 
       Isnull(Sum(CONVERT(INT, Amount)), '0') AS Amount 
FROM   HMS_DiagnosisTransactions 
WHERE  TransDate BETWEEN '05/01/2015' AND '07/24/2015' 
GROUP  BY CONVERT(NVARCHAR(15), TransDate, 103) 
ORDER  BY CONVERT(NVARCHAR(15), TransDate, 103)
```

it is showing like

```
20/05/2015
20/06/2015
21/05/2015
22/07/2015
```

but i want

```
20/05/2015
21/05/2015
20/06/2015
22/07/2015
```

Comment: `ORDER BY Transdate`

Comment: This type of formatting really should be done in the front end. It seems that you want the output ordered by the actual date? Just take off the formatting in your order by predicate so it will order by the date value instead of string representation.

Comment: You are sorting by the string representation not the date. You need to cast the results to a date

Comment: @wewesthemenace: You can't use a value in `order by` that isn't in the `group by`.

Comment: @Guffa, of course. I was just pointing out the general idea. That's why it's not an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the `TransDate` in the `Group By`(truncate the time), then you can use it in the `Order By`:

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(15), TransDate, 103)  AS TransDate, 
       Isnull(Sum(CONVERT(INT, Amount)), '0') AS Amount 
FROM   HMS_DiagnosisTransactions 
WHERE  TransDate BETWEEN '05/01/2015' AND '07/24/2015' 
GROUP  BY CONVERT(NVARCHAR(15), TransDate, 103), DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, TransDate), 0) 
ORDER BY DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, TransDate), 0)
```

This works even in SQL-Server 2005 and below. 2008 introduced the `Date` datatype which has no time portion.  Then you just have to cast it to `Date`:

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(15), TransDate, 103)  AS TransDate, 
       Isnull(Sum(CONVERT(INT, Amount)), '0') AS Amount 
FROM   HMS_DiagnosisTransactions 
WHERE  TransDate BETWEEN '05/01/2015' AND '07/24/2015' 
GROUP  BY CONVERT(NVARCHAR(15), TransDate, 103), CAST(TransDate as Date) 
ORDER  BY CAST(TransDate as Date)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the grouping actually has a purpose, so that you need to use the grouped value. Convert the string back to a date:

```
ORDER BY CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(15), TransDate, 103), 103)
```

Comment: @CarlSixsmith: You can't use a value in `order by` that isn't in the `group by`. Putting the unconverted value in the `group by` would change the result.

Comment: Not downvoted, but you can't use this order-by without adding it to the group-by.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: No, that's not needed. The part `CONVERT(NVARCHAR(15), TransDate, 103)` is in the `group by`. In `order by` you can can use a value from `group by` as part of an expression.

Comment: Only if the  expression is the same or the column is used in the Group-By which is not the case. If you would add `Transdate` the result would be different

Comment: @TimSchmelter: You are mistaken. Try it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can declare year/month/day values as `DATEPART`, group by them too, while doing all of this in a derived table. Then just re-query it.

```
SELECT T.TransDate, T.Amount
FROM (
    SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(15), TransDate, 103) AS TransDate
        , COALESCE(SUM(CONVERT(INT, Amount)), '0') AS Amount
        , DATEPART(DD, TransDate) AS DD
        , DATEPART(MM, TransDate) AS MM
        , DATEPART(YY, TransDate) AS YY
    FROM HMS_DiagnosisTransactions
    WHERE TransDate BETWEEN '05/01/2015' AND '07/24/2015'
    GROUP BY CONVERT(NVARCHAR(15), TransDate, 103)
        , DATEPART(DD, TransDate)
        , DATEPART(MM, TransDate)
        , DATEPART(YY, TransDate)
    ) AS T
ORDER BY T.YY, T.MM, T.DD;
```